# Authenticating Apache website against WIN SERVER 2008 Active Directory

Tags: networking, server, windows, apache2, samba

I have a quick question, maybe a noob one :D

I currently have Windows server 2008 running on one of my servers, that server is the Domain Controller, running active directory with all the users.

My second server is running Ubuntu and it will be the Apache server.

The website I am creating will have login system, which will use users from the Windows Active Directory.

Question is, how do I make the Apache server see the users from the windows AD? Do I need to run Samba and synchronise the users so I can  get my PHP script to pick up the users from Samba AD? If yes, then how do I synchronise that since I never used Samba before.

Any suggestions are welcome!

This is the first time working on a project like this, so I'm a bit lost, sorry if its a new question!

Thanks :)

Comment: more apache topic. AD is just like any LDAP. check here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html

Answer (score 0):

This is something that really should be handled at the application level and not at the server level (it makes testing, easier), without knowing the language your using you can existing libraries to connect to active directory to auth your users or roll your own, you can see me getting berated over my code on code review (just go through my profile) to get an idea (its in php)